# Is Date/Time dimension recommended in my case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I'm designing a data warehouse that has calls and telephony data in it. In my fact table (fact calls) I do have multiple `DATETIME` fields such as `CallStart, CallEnd, CallAnswered, CallRecordSaved`, etc... (all of those have `year, month, day, hour, minute, second`)

My question is should I save those fields as `DATETIME` data type or should I reference them to another table (Date/Time dimension) taking into account that I'm planning to generate a cube out of that DW and planning to calculate time difference between some of those DateTime values.

What do you think ??

Comment: If you want to calculate the difference between two values, then I would recommend storing them using the underlying data types.  Having to use dimension tables for differences is cumbersome.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree but I have to ask if doing analysis without date/time dimension would be much heavier (example: getting calls, by month, day etc..) ??

Comment: Agree with both Gordon and Fourat.  I would have CallStart as datetime, and then Duration int as seconds.   All the benefits of the datetime without having to calculate duration for each aggregation function

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I do have Duration and CallDuration int as seconds in my fact table, but I do have to store the CallStart, CallEnd, CallAnswered etc.. for historical purposes. So either I'm storing them as datetime values or as references to time dimension.

Comment: Given that you are designing a data warehouse, in future you may be called to analyse things like weekend vs weekday calls, holidays vs non-holidays, days of week, etc - all these become easy with separate Date/Time dimension tables.

Comment: I must admit I don't understand the question. A call can start and end at whatever time, so how would your dimension table look like? An entry for February 3, 2010, 14:06 when a call started (and the record would probably used for only that one call)? Or one table with the years, another with the days, etc? I don't understand what you have in mind.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I do have multiple fields of type datetime (ex: call starts at 2016/05/31 23:51:22 and ends at 2016/06/01 00:04:32 and the record (mp3) is saved at 2016/06/01 00:05:01 .....). My question is if I should put those dates in the fact table as datetime fields or I should reference each/some of them to a time/date dimension table.

Comment: So rather than store 2016/06/01 00:05:01 directly in the table you would store it in a dimension table with dim_id 1234 and store that ID 1234 in your facts table? What could be the benefit of this? You could do this with any column, not just dates, every number, every string, but I don't see how this could possible improve anything.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner it seams that you don't know the notion of the time dimension in Business Intelligence, check this: http://www.kimballgroup.com/1997/07/its-time-for-time/

Comment: @Fourat: Thanks for the link. I understand that there are situations where you'd have such a table in your datawarehouse. But these are actually the same when you'd have them in the source OLTP database. As long as you simply deal with months, years, calendar weeks, etc., all these can be gotten easily from a datetime, but as soon as you talk about fiscal years, off-work days, etc. you'd have some kind of calendar table in your database - whether it be OLTP or OLAP doesn't matter much in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I like the earlier comments and agree you only need to do a full dimension in one field - callStart. But what call volumes are you looking at? Average of 1 call a minute, 10 per minute etc. How peaky are your peaks? If the call rate varies smoothly then you can increase your time granularity. Do you need date and time in the same dimension. Could you have time buckets and the date as separate dimensions. Similarly with the duration. Hold it as a duration and as a bucket value. You already have the date from call start. 
**edit**
To come back to the question. I would store the datetime for each,  but I would only link the start to a dimension. The rest would be available for display but not navigation

Comment: I do have to save the datetime values (for history purposes), so I'm not doing any calculations in the ETL. Meanwhile I like the idea of referencing the CallStart to a date/time dimension and the other fields as datetime in a separate dimension. Also, now I'm getting 100+ call per minute (average) and growing

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past is have a date/time dimension for the most important date(s) and then had another dimension (say, "Call" in your case) which stores a whole load of dates that might be useful in one place. This dimension doesn't have to have all the columns of the date table and typically will just have date/time fields for those extra properties.

This gives you some of the best of both worlds, though it may not suit every case - it does have the advantage of being able to pull those dimension fields back into the fact as keys to the date/time table in a view if it turns out to be necessary, so it's kind of forward-compatible in that respect.